# Does stress make you age faster, biologically?

Tags: biology, environmental-health

[Excess cortisol can damage the hippocampus](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2367228/), [and we also know that stress can reduce the length of telomeres](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-athletes-way/201404/emotional-distress-can-speed-cellular-aging), [which can lead to a shortened lifespan](http://www.pnas.org/content/109/5/1743.full).

But does stress accelerate aging in other ways too, [like accelerate skin wrinkling](https://www.sharecare.com/health/stress-reduction/how-does-stress-cause-wrinkles)?

Comment: I think we need to focus the question. Obviously a stressed 50-year old is still 50 years old, so the title is misleading. The assumed knowledge is rather advanced - some references would help. But mostly, let's find a single notable claim we can address here, or the question is too broad.

Comment: I added some references and narrowed down a bit the question on a suggested edit. I hope it holds the original meaning and still gets more adequate to the site.